# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError -Android

Tags: android

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Failed to allocate a 1631415409byte allocation with 2474340 free bytes and 380 MB until OOM
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:548)
```

**Mainfest.xml**

```
  <application
        android:name=".globalexceptionhandler.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Resize your image

Answer (score -1):

Try using the latest version of Volley. Issue seems to be fixed in https://github.com/google/volley/issues/12.

`compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`

Comment: Thanks ..I will try